# react-google-maps Content Security Policy

Tags: reactjs, google-maps, next.js, react-google-maps

I am integrating react-google-maps in nextjs. Every thing works fine but when map is opened the images are not loaded:
I get Refused to load image because it violates the following content security policy directive : "img-src *"
What does this mean and how to resolve this? Is this related to my domain or my app server?
Note, Locally every thing works fine
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You need to set you Content Security Policy Header to accept from the locations

Header set Content-Security-Policy  "default-src 'self'  https://www.googletagmanager.com *.images.google.com

something like that (not sure what ones you will need to add)

Comment: somehow google-map-react overrides what I set in the meta